# Почему разняться результаты на тестовой выборке и при тестировании вручную (sklearn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, sklearn

Появилась задача бинарной классификации (депрессивный/нейтральный текст), набор данных пример по 30к. для каждого класса. Решил что использую SVC для создания модели и написал небольшой pipeline для облегчения работы.

```
pipe_svc_dep = Pipeline([
                ("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: tokenize_normalize_text(x, min_word_length=3, max_word=100), lowercase=False)),
                ("scaler", StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
                ('svc', svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1))

])
pipe_svc_dep.fit(train_df["clean_text"],train_df["label"])
```

После обучения прогнал модель через тестовую выборку и результаты порадовали.

```
prediction_svc_dep = pipe_svc_dep.predict(test_df["clean_text"])
print(f'Точность: {accuracy_score(prediction_svc_dep, test_df["label"])}')
print(f'F1: {f1_score(prediction_svc_dep, test_df["label"])}')
print(confusion_matrix(prediction_svc_dep, test_df["label"]))

>>>Точность: 0.9396
>>>F1: 0.940221694378464
>>>[[4646  268]
    [ 336 4750]]
```

Но когда начал тестировать вручную, то озадачился результатом, примерно 90% всех фраз определились в первый класс (депрессивный) хотя посты содержали разные тональности, разные размеры.

*предварительно данные были очищены небольшой функцией

```
def tokenize_normalize_text(text, min_word_length=2, max_word=300):
    tokens = ' '.join([re.sub(r'\b(https?:?\s?//|www\.?)\w+?[\w+_:./0-9]+', "", text).strip()])
    tokens = word_tokenize(tokens, language="russian")
    tokens = [i.lower() for i in tokens]
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if i not in punctuation]
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop_word]
    tokens = [snowball.stem(i) for i in tokens]
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if len(i)>min_word_length]
    tokens = tokens[:max_word]
    tokens =' '.join(tokens)

    
    return tokens
```

Так же были опробованы модели LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionCV, LinearSVC. На первых двух результат был похожий:

LogisticRegression

```
>>>Точность: 0.9359
>>>F1: 0.9359
```

LogisticRegressionCV

```
>>>Точность: 0.9425
>>>F1: 0.9432
```

Собственно, почему при тестировании на тестовой выборке результаты отличные, а при тестировании в ручную отвратительные?? Подскажите хотя бы  в какую сторону смотреть, а то опыта в данной теме не хватает.
Спасибо.

Comment: Тут главное что непонятно: что такое "тестирование вручную", как оно у вас выглядит?

Comment: Ну и с пайплайнами нужно осторожно, нужно чётко понимать, на каких данных вы тренируетесь и на каких предсказываете. Где нужно тренировать заново и т.д. Да, кстати, ещё непонятно, какую вы берёте тестовую выборку, лучше проверяться на кросс-валидации, просто тестовая выборка может быть весьма смещённой. И ваши "ручные" примеры тоже могут быть смещёнными, нужно смотреть, чем они отличаются.

Comment: Тестирование вручную - это когда я сам подаю модели на вход какую либо фразу и получаю результат.
pipe_svc_dep.predict(["сегодня днем был у бабушки в гостях и кушал окрошку"])

Ну данные у меня разбиты на 2 набора, на одном обучаю на втором тестирую.
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df_neu_dep, test_size=10000)

А кросс-валидация пока мне совершенно не понятно как работает, я смотрел примеры ее работы через sklearn, но я не могу понять как мне это использовать, т.е. я понимаю для чего нужна кросс-валидация, но не понимаю как её правильно использовать.

Comment: Т.е. я использую scores = cross_val_score(pipe_svc_dep, train_df['clean_text'],train_df['label'] , cv=5), на выходе получаю набор значение и что с этим делать не понимаю....

Comment: Ну, выглядит нормально так то. А числа вы покажите, которые на кросс-валидации получаются. Так то от них нужно посмотреть `np.mean` и `np.std`. Будет понятно, какой средний скор по фолдам и какой разброс. Так то я бы посмотрел, что не так с теми фразами, которые вы тестируете - может там есть слова, которых не было при обучении, хотя может это и не главное.

Comment: А так то у вас порядка 600 неправильных результатов в тесте, может все ваши ручные фразы такие неудачные, что попали в эту неудачную выборку. Я бы вообще взял те фразы из теста, в которых модель ошибается, и повнимательнее на них посмотрел, что там не так.

Comment: Результаты кросс-валидации. Можно попросить вас пояснить что тут написано и как это интерпретировать для пронимая.

{'fit_time': array([798.32152057, 776.56821489, 799.48993492, 817.62484145,
       838.77889824]), 'score_time': array([ 97.23099041,  97.14822197,  99.18411636, 129.83128142,
        99.24445248]), 'test_score': array([0.94087713, 0.93560326, 0.93745374, 0.94059956, 0.93911354])}

Comment: "Я бы вообще взял те фразы из теста, в которых модель ошибается" Наверное да, если бы я понимал как  это посмотреть ))

Comment: Ну что-то типа `test_df.loc[prediction_svc_dep != test_df["label"], "clean_text"]` - это те будут тексты, на которых модель ошиблась. Всегда полезно посмотреть на них глазами, вдруг там что-то необычное обнаружится.

Comment: Если эти скоры допустим лежат в переменной `scores`, то вот так можно напечатать: `print(f"Средний скор на кросс-валидации: {scores['test_score'].mean():0.3f} ± {scores['test_score'].std():0.3f}")`, получится: `Средний скор на кросс-валидации: 0.939 ± 0.002` Это довольно равномерно по фолдам, и это хорошо. Значит проблема в конкретных примерах, разбирайтесь с ними. В целом модель хорошая.

Comment: Спасибо большое, за всю информацию